Log Pearson Type III Distribution
Has anyone managed to implement the Log-Pearson type III distribution in Wolfram. To determine the parameters of the distribution over the data array using the FindDisributionParameters function?
Here is an example of an array of source data.
data = {10.9, 9.7, 6.7, 5.5, 9.6, 5.5, 9.4, 8.7, 10.6, 9.9, 8.7, 7.7,6.5, 11.3, 9.5, 
10.5, 6.9, 9.3, 9.0, 10.9, 10.3, 8.2, 9.3, 8.5, 7.1, 9.4, 6.9, 7.0, 7.7, 8.3, 11.3, 
9.7, 10.3, 10.3, 6.2, 9.2,10.8, 11.1, 9.1, 7.8, 6.4, 9.4, 8.3, 5.5, 5.1, 10.4, 11.6, 
12.4,11.6, 11.8, 8.1, 9.6, 11.2, 9.7, 10.2, 10.8, 11.2, 11.0, 10.0,10.2, 8.9, 11.7, 
9.8, 12.4, 10.6, 13.3, 11.5, 10.1};


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Five parameters of PDF[TransformedDistribution[Exp[x],    x \[Distributed] PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0]], t] which results in Piecewise[{{Sqrt[a1/b0]/(E^((a0 + a1*Log[t])^2/(2*a1*b0))*Sqrt[2*Pi]*t),     b1 == 0 && E^(-(b0/b1)) - t <= 0 && a1*b0 > 0},    {(a1*((a1*(b0 + b1*Log[t]))/b1^2)^((a1*b0 - a0*b1)/b1^2))/     (b1*E^((a1*(b0 + b1*Log[t]))/b1^2)*t*      Gamma[(a1*b0 - a0*b1 + b1^2)/b1^2]),     b1 != 0 && E^(-(b0/b1)) - t <= 0 && a1*b0 + a1*b1*Log[t] > 0}}, 0] are to many for

FindDistributionParameters[data, distr,   ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "FindMaximum"}].

Have you actually tried to determine the parameters using your example? It will immediately give an error

There seems to be two questions:

Does FindDistributionParameters work for the Log Pearson Type III
distribution?
Does the above work for my data?

The answer for 1 is Yes and the answer for 2 is "It can work but there is a poor fit".  (And "poor" is attached to the expectations of a good fit from this data rather than any problems with Mathematica - although the documentation for PearsonDistribution could certainly include more details.)
If one has data from a Log Pearson Type III distribution, then one can take the logs of that data and fit a Pearson Type III distribution with the same parameters.
The usual parameterization of a Pearson Type III distribution has the pdf with 3 parameters defined in the following manner:
pdf = (1/(Abs[a] Gamma[b])) Exp[-(x - c)/a] ((x - c)/a)^(b - 1)

But to unify the definition of all Pearson distributions, Mathematica uses 5 parameters:
pdf2 = FullSimplify[PDF[PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0], x], 
  Assumptions -> {b1 != 0, a1  (b0 + b1  x) > 0}]

Note that b2 isn't even used.  Consider the following re-parameterization:
substitutions = Solve[{(a1 (b0 + b1 x))/b1^2 == (x - c)/a, 
  (a1 b0 - a0 b1)/b1^2 == b - 1, a1/b1 == 1/Abs[a]}, {a1, a0, b1, b0}][[1]]//FullSimplify
(* {a1 -> b1/Abs[a], a0 -> (b1 (a - a b - c + x - x Sign[a]))/a, 
   b0 -> -((b1 (c - x + x Sign[a]))/Sign[a])} *)
pdf2x = pdf2 /. substitutions // FullSimplify
(* -((E^((c - x)/a) ((-c + x)/a)^b Sign[a])/((c - x) Gamma[b])) *)

We see that the parameters a1, a0, and b0 are all multiples of b1 so we can just replace b1 with the number 1 as there are really only 3 parameters necessary.  Even without the b1 substitution we can show that pdf is equivalent to pdf2:
pdf2x == (1/(Abs[a] Gamma[b])) Exp[-(x - c)/a] ((x - c)/a)^(b - 1) // FullSimplify
(* True *)

So setting b1=1 and b2=0 we can proceed in the "obvious" manner:
data = {10.9, 9.7, 6.7, 5.5, 9.6, 5.5, 9.4, 8.7, 10.6, 9.9, 8.7, 7.7, 
   6.5, 11.3, 9.5, 10.5, 6.9, 9.3, 9.0, 10.9, 10.3, 8.2, 9.3, 8.5, 
   7.1, 9.4, 6.9, 7.0, 7.7, 8.3, 11.3, 9.7, 10.3, 10.3, 6.2, 9.2, 
   10.8, 11.1, 9.1, 7.8, 6.4, 9.4, 8.3, 5.5, 5.1, 10.4, 11.6, 12.4, 
   11.6, 11.8, 8.1, 9.6, 11.2, 9.7, 10.2, 10.8, 11.2, 11.0, 10.0, 
   10.2, 8.9, 11.7, 9.8, 12.4, 10.6, 13.3, 11.5, 10.1};

mle = FindDistributionParameters[Log[data], 
  PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, 0, 1, b0]]
(* {a1 -> 1708.23, a0 -> -3785.91, b0 -> 78.7404} *)

Show[Histogram[Log[data], "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Log(data)", "Probability density"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1.5, 2.8}, {0, All}}],
 Plot[PDF[PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, 0, 1, b0] /. mle, z], {z, 1.5, 10}, PlotRange -> All]]


Note that the parameter estimates appear extreme.  We can estimate the standard errors and the parameter correlation matrix:
(* Obtain estimates of the standard errors *)
logL = LogLikelihood[PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, 0, 1, b0], Log[data]];
cov = -Inverse[D[logL, {{a1, a0, b0}, 2}] /. mle];
se = Sqrt[Diagonal[cov]]
(* {5141.7, 11398.5, 243.136} *)

(* Correlation matrix *)
cor = IdentityMatrix[3];
Do[cor[[i, j]] = cov[[i, j]]/Sqrt[cov[[i, i]] cov[[j, j]]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
cor // MatrixForm


Note that the standard errors are large compared to the parameter estimates and the correlations are all near +1 or -1 indicating a poor fit for this data.

For this data, the built-in functions are able to select parameters for the Pearson distribution type 3. The fact that it may or may not suit me is not so important. It is necessary to show that it selects but according to the criteria it is very bad. The program as a whole works very very very poorly with non-built-in or transformed distributions. She doesn't pick at all. For this reason the question arose. And I don't understand the meaning of the code you provided above. Why should I see you using the built-in Pearson distribution?

I'm not understanding your comment.  Why wouldn't you want to use the built-in Pearson distribution?  The only 2 reasons I can think of are (1) the documentation isn't clear and (2) the particular parameterization can result in highly correlated parameter estimators.  "The program as a whole works very very very poorly with non-built-in or transformed distributions."  This certainly occurs sometimes but do you have a particular example that worked poorly?  (That would likely be a different question.)

@JimB thank you for the instructional answer, particularly the estimates of standard errors . +1 :)

Edit:
Provided with the definition of Log-Pearson type III distribution as TransformedDistribution[Exp[x],x \[Distributed] PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0]],
we know that Log[data] follows a Pearson type III distribution, which means that we can determine the parameters of the distribution with Log[data] and distribution PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0], like this
FindDistributionParameters[Log[data], 
 PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0], 
 ParameterEstimator -> {"MaximumLikelihood", Method -> "NMaximize"}]

However, this sample of data gives a bad fitting, it returns a warning
NMinimize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded. The full data may provide a good estimation.

Your words " mathematica has already implemented the Log-Pearson type III distribution" do not correspond to reality because PDF[TransformedDistribution[Exp[x],    x \[Distributed] PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0]], t] results in Piecewise[{{Sqrt[a1/b0]/(E^((a0 + a1*Log[t])^2/(2*a1*b0))*Sqrt[2*Pi]*t),     b1 == 0 && E^(-(b0/b1)) - t <= 0 && a1*b0 > 0},    {(a1*((a1*(b0 + b1*Log[t]))/b1^2)^((a1*b0 - a0*b1)/b1^2))/     (b1*E^((a1*(b0 + b1*Log[t]))/b1^2)*t*      Gamma[(a1*b0 - a0*b1 + b1^2)/b1^2]),     b1 != 0 && E^(-(b0/b1)) - t <= 0 && a1*b0 + a1*b1*Log[t] > 0}}, 0].

Also the documentation to PearsonDistribution (see the Details section) writes "PearsonDistribution[3,…] includes NormalDistribution and GammaDistribution". I think you missed PearsonDistribution[3,…] with LogPearsonDistribution[3,…] which is defined as TransformedDistribution[Exp[x],    x \[Distributed] PearsonDistribution[3, a1, a0, b2, b1, b0]]

simply adding TransformedDistribution[Exp[x] did not solve the problem. Even the addition of approximate parameter values proposed by ChatGPT did not allow us to obtain adequate parameters

@user64494 Updated.

You've made a mistake again: LogPearson should be fitted to data, not to Log[data].

@user64494 LogPearson should be fitted to data, and thus Pearson should be fitted to Log[data]

Why do you think so? Could you kindly give a reference to groun your claim? TIA and deep regard.

@user64494 Here's some grounds:  Just like a  the log of LogNormal random variable is Normal, the log of Log Pearson Type III random variable is a Pearson Type III.  As Mathematica only provides the Pearson Type III distribution directly and not the Log Pearson Type III distribution, taking the logs and then performing the estimation seems the way to go.

Thank you. I got it.
